# Android Thread difference between AsyncTask, Executor and Service

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio

I'm a bit confused about multi-threading in Android. Could you tell me the difference and the use case of AsyncTask, Executor and Service ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)

Read [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)

Executor is just an object that executes submitted Runnable tasks.

Read [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor)

Service does not relate to multi-threading at all.  A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process; the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process unless you specify otherwise.

Read [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=ru)